# CRM 2016: There is no Email Configuration under Settings

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-crm

I'm trying to create an Email Server Profile as described in this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/administering-dynamics-365/mt703269(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

When I go to Settings --> There is no Email Configuration tab/icon, etc. showing in this area

What's missing? or is there some other configuration that needs to be changed to show it?  I have both System Administrator and System Customizer roles assigned to my account.

The version we're running is:

Microsoft Dynamics 365 Version 1612 (8.2.2.112) on-premises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this on the Dynamics CRM Community site along with other information from other sites.  I passed this information along to our CRM Developer and it was resolved.  The following articles is what helped solve this problem:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2013/implementation-guide/dn486920(v=crm.6)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#BKMK_ImportSolution

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg309424(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

https://technologyblog.rsmus.com/microsoft/dynamics-365-customer-engagement/restoring-email-configuration-option-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-settings-area/